# Saving Buffer on Postgres bytea with TypeORM only store 10 bytes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to save some images on a postgres db, but only 10 bytes of data are being saved.

The flow is something like this:

I receive a base64 encoded string on my server, then i load that to a Buffer, set it to my entity and save it. 
But then a try to restore that information from db and i'm getting  only 10 bytes of data, verified with octet_length() on a query.

My entity attribute definition:

```js
@Column({ "name": "entima_imagem", "type": "bytea", "nullable": false })
entima_imagem: Buffer;
```

The code where i receive the data and save it:

```js
entity.entima_imagem = Buffer.from(base64String, "base64");
const repository = this.getRepositoryTarget(Entity);
const saved = await repository.save<any>(entity);
```

On the server, before saving, i'm writing the file on disc and i can visualize it without problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on that comment https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2878#issuecomment-432725569 and the idea of bytea hex format from there https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-binary.html I did the following:

Decoded the Buffer to a hex string, escaped it with \x and then loaded it to a Buffer again.

```js
entity.entima_imagem = Buffer.from("\\x" + Buffer.from(base64String, "base64").toString("hex"));
```

Now the data is saved without problems and i can retrieve them just as it's supposed to be.

It didn't look so elegant, but solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. It looks like typeorm has problems with 0x00 byte. It slices everything starting from first 0 byte.

A similar workaround worked for me:

```
@Column({ type: "bytea", nullable: false })
public file: Buffer;
```

while saving:

```
log.file = ("\\x" + file.toString( "hex" )) as any;
```

Creating a buffer from "\\x"+content string as @JDuwe suggested didn't work for me.
I had to provide a string to typeorm, not Buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe since the last answer postgres or typeorm solved it, but on the latest version of both i managed to make this work without any "hack"
here is the code for entity column

```
@Column({
    name: 'imageData',
    type: 'bytea',
    nullable: false,
})
imageData: Buffer;
```

and only thing i did that converted base64 string to Buffer, but this is unrelated to typeorm

```
 constructor(imageDataBase64: string) {
    if (imageDataBase64) {
        this.imageData = Buffer.from(imageDataBase64, 'base64');
    }
}
```

Even I use sync feature of typeorm

During retrival:

```
imageData.toString('base64')
```

and i got back the original base64 string which can be inserted into webpage as image